# Is there a better way to assign a default value for next()

Tags: python

```
url_params = {}
for i in t:
    try:
        url_params[i] = t.next()
    except:
        url_params[i] = None
```

Because this just looks silly to me. I'm converting a list to a dict by pairing up neighboring elements. There are cases, however, where I won't always have a pair. The tailing element is still important but it's value isn't important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more easily done like this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
url_params = dict(izip_longest(*[iter(t)] * 2))
```

Example: For `t = range(11)`, this produces

```
{0: 1, 2: 3, 4: 5, 6: 7, 8: 9, 10: None}
```

Comment: This wins. Thank you a million. I was using this wrong earlier and got frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

Also works:

```
>>> dict(zip(t[::2], t[1::2]+[None]))
{0: 1, 2: 3, 4: 5, 6: 7, 8: 9, 10: None}
```